# height 100% height scrolling div inside height 100% div

Tags: css, resize, scroll

so I have looked all over stackoverflow looking for a solution but can't seem to find one that fits me. I am trying to solve this issue without using javascript but basically my first challenge was to create a div to the left and have it scroll while staying fixed with the browser size.

But now, I am having issues placing another height 100% div into the height 100% div.

I do feel i need to place all of the buttons and the scrolling into one div because otherwise it creates problems with the div on the right.

The problem is that no matter what I try the child div seems to go out of the parent at the bottom regardless of the positioning. I would like the height to stay 100% with browser resizing. like so:

[Working Fiddle Before Buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/7pjTx/embedded/result/)

When I add the buttons, this is what happens:

[Not working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQhUH/embedded/result/)

**HTML**

```
<div class = "main">
    <div class="head">Header</div>
</div>

<div class="left">
    <div class="inleft">
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="containerRight">
    A

    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
    <div class="post">A</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 * {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box; 
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
} 
body {
    padding:60px 0 0 300px; /* 60 — header height*/
    margin:0;
}
.main,
.left,
.containerRight{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.main {
    min-width:100%;
    height:60px;
    margin-top: -60px;  /* 60 — header height*/
    margin-left: -300px;
}

.left {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.containerRight {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.head {
    float: right;   
}
```

Comment: Hi, not to be rude but your html is quite messy and hard to read, I want to help but I don't have time to clean it all up and match tags to try find your problem. Also could you provide the code with the buttons, I had a look at the fiddle and the html seems to be off.

Please tidy it up and I am sure you will get more assistance.

Comment: Sorry about that I was editing the post and it seems that you did that for me. Very sorry about that! much appreciated. As for the buttons I am going to inserting jquery into them so just them there for the placement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compensate for the height of the buttons that are sitting above your `.inside div`. The `.left` div has height of 100% and so does inside, but it's being pushed down by the buttons in addition to the 100% height. You could try adding some padding to the top ( 55px ) of .inside and a negative margin to pull it back up ( but I am assuming you'll be adding more buttons maybe? ). So you could also move your overflow-y: scroll to the `.left` div to hide everything getting pushed out of the bottom from .`inside`.

Comment: Hey Evan thanks for the response. I added padding-top: 55px; to .inside and also placed the margin-top: -55px; to .inside Is this correct? Those are all the button i am going to have. As for putting the overflow-y on the left I want the three buttons up top to always be fixed that it is always visible to the user.

Comment: I took a look at the fiddle and I like how the left and right div are both flush, but I do not want a fixed height I would like the two divs to stay flush with no space at the bottom always adjusting to the browser height. In the browser window I would only like the two divs left and right to be scrollable.